# Compute conditional distribution without joint distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

I'm trying to solve problem 3.6 of [Elements of causal inference](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/elements-causal-inference) by Peters, Janzing and Schölkopf. And I'm stuck, I'm afraid I'm missing something that might be trivial... the problem is the following:

Given the structual causal model $\mathfrak{C}$ (SCM):
$$\begin{align}C &:= N_C \\ E &:= 4C +N_E \end{align}$$
Where $N_C,N_E\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Show that $P_{C|E=2}^{\mathfrak{C}}$ is a Gaussian distribution: $$C|E=2 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{8}{17},\sigma^2=\frac{1}{17}\right)$$

So, I know that the conditional probability mass function of $C$ given $E=e$ is given by 
$$P_{C|E=y}^{\mathfrak{C}}=\frac{P_{CE}^\mathfrak{C}}{P_E^{\mathfrak{C}}}$$
And I can easily compute $P_E^{\mathfrak{C}} = \mathcal{N}(0,17)$, but if I don't have the joint distribution, how can I compute the conditional distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lagrange multipliers to solve this, but one approach is related to a [Cross Validated question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random) using properties of the sums of independent normal distributed random variables

Let $D = 4N_C$, so $D \sim \mathcal N(0,16)$ and $E=D+N_E$ with $D$ and  $N_E$ normal and independent so $E \sim \mathcal N(0,17)$

Then, using [the linked answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9073), conditioned on a particular value of $E$ you have the difference in the conditional mean from the unconditional mean for $D$ being the difference between the value of $E$ and its unconditional mean multiplied by its share of the unconditional variance of $E$, so in this case with $E=2$ you get $2\times\frac{16}{16+1}=\frac{32}{17}$.  The conditional variance for $D$ is $\frac{16 \times 1}{16+1} = \frac{16}{17}$ making the conditional distribution of $D \sim \mathcal N\left(\frac{32}{17},\frac{16}{17}\right)$

But you are actually interested in the conditional distribution of $C=\frac{D}{4}$ given $E=2$, so dividing the mean by $4$ and the variance by $4^2$ you get  $\mathcal N\left(\frac{8}{17},\frac{1}{17}\right)$